# Unfixed structure in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have A structure named TOWRITE.  I want to write the contents the structure into a file.  But one thing is size of a member of structure is unfixed.  It depends on data received from another source.  Is it possible to write structure by easy way.  please refer below code snippet.

thanks

```
typedef struct TOWRITE
{
   DWORD dwHeader;
   WORD datacount;
   LPBYTE lpData;
   WORD checksum;
}

TOWRITE towrite;
ZeroMemory( &towrite, sizeof( TOWRITE ));
towrite.lpData = (LPBYTE) new BYTE[256];

towrite.dwHeader = 0xF1F1E1E1;
towrite.datacount = 256;
towrite.cheksum = 3849;
CopyMemory( towrite.lpData, szTemp, 256 );

.....

.....

.....

f.write( (LPBYTE)&towrite, sizeof(TOWRITE) );
....
....
....
....
```

Comment: No, you are just writing the pointer to your data, which isn't very useful. You have to write the data pointed to by `lpData` as well. There are no shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just i modified my code to

```
typedef struct TOWRITE
{
 DWORD dwHeader;
 WORD datacount;
}

TOWRITE towrite;
LPBYTE lpData;
WORD checksum;

ZeroMemory( &towrite, sizeof( TOWRITE ));
lpData = (LPBYTE) new BYTE[256];

towrite.dwHeader = 0xF1F1E1E1;
towrite.datacount = 256;
cheksum = 3849;
CopyMemory( lpData, szTemp, 256 );

.....

.....

.....

f.write( (LPBYTE)&towrite, sizeof(TOWRITE) );
f.write( (LPBYTE)&lpData, datacount );
f.write( (LPBYTE)&checksum, 2 );
....
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct TOWRITE
{
   DWORD dwHeader;
   WORD datacount;
   WORD checksum;
   LPBYTE lpData; //Put the ptr at the end
}

// - sizeof(LPBYTE) avoid the ptr @ to be written
f.write( (LPBYTE)&towrite, sizeof(TOWRITE) - sizeof(LPBYTE));  

// write the ptr data.
// sorry I don't know windows C.
// fix the size of the array element :)
f.write( towrite.lpData, towrite.datacount * sizeof(????));
```

Comment: sizeof(TOWRITE) - sizeof(LPBYTE), Here what will be size of LPBYTE

Comment: thanks for solution, inspired from your solution, i modified the code and use 3 write method to write structure, lpdata and checksum

Answer (score 1):

You can try tpl library: http://tpl.sourceforge.net/

Tpl is a library for serializing C data. The data is stored in its natural binary form. The API is small and tries to stay "out of the way". Compared to using XML, tpl is faster and easier to use in C programs. Tpl can serialize many C data types, including structures.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply, but i can't use any external library

Comment: In this case it will be better if you will serialize you structure member by member to avoid possible problems with alignment...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to write structure by easy way.
>
> i can't use any external library

Then no. Libraries *are* the easy way, whether TPL for C or the excellent Boost.Serialization for C++. C and C++ do not have *built-in* mechanisms for serializing data structures. So if you're not able to use a library, then you're going to have to hand-code the serialization yourself.

Answer (score 1):

just use two write calls:

```
f.write ((LPBYTE)&towrite, sizeof(TOWRITE));
f.write ((LPBYTE)&towrite.lpData, towrite.datacount * sizeof(BYTE));
```

and then you can read it again with:

```
TOWRITE towrite;
f.read ((LPBYTE)&towrite, sizeof(TOWRITE));
towrite.lpData = (LPBYTE) new BYTE[towrite.datacount];
f.read ((LPBYTE)&towrite.lpData, towrite.datacount * sizeof(BYTE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this approach may avoid redundant data that sometimes come as a result of structure padding.

```
char* data =malloc(sizeof(towrite)-sizeof(LPBYTE)+var_data);
CopyMemory( data, towrite.dwHeader, sizeof(DWORD) );
CopyMemory( data, towrite.datacount, sizeof(WORD) );
CopyMemory( data, szTemp, datalength);
CopyMemory( data, towrite.checksum, sizeof(WORD) );
f.write( data,sizeof(towrite)-sizeof(LPBYTE)+var_data);
```